# Producer/Consumer Multi-Threading TCP

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp, producer-consumer

I'm new in the multi-threading and TCP world and I'm learning it with an assignment regarding Producer/Consumer problem.
It ask this:

**N** concurrent **Producers** must be connected to a **Worker** (it is also okay to change N from code). **Producer** and **Worker** run in the same process. This process also acts as a **TCP Server**. Only one **Consumer** runs in a second process. This second process must connect as **TCP Client** to the first process. After processing, all processed workloads must be received by all connected clients (so multiple **Consumers** are allowed, one **Consumer** per process).

Interface between **Producer** and **Worker** in order to optimize processing. Print on console in a way that is easy to compare results **Worker** and **Consumer**.

To be done in **C#** with **Visual Studio** and **.Net Framework >= 4.5**. The two .exes must be in the same solution. Use any design patterns, if applicable.
Implementation must be done without the use of Tasks.

---

**WORKLOAD**:
There are 3 different loads (A, B, C). Each load is represented by a class, each class has an "**Execute**" method that simulates the execution of the load.
The "**Execute**" method simulates the load using a **Thread.Sleep**. The result of the "**Execute**" is an array of random bytes (from 0 to 255) which is inserted into a property. The length changes according to the type.

- **Load A**:

  - Processing time: 1 second
  - Random byte array length: 100
- **Load B**:

  - Processing time: 5 seconds
  - Random byte array length: 200
- **Load C**:

  - Processing time: 10 seconds
  - Random byte array length: 300

Each load is identified by the manufacturer's ID and an integer. The class also has the following properties:

- **Production Timestamp**: assigned at the time of production
- **Processing Timestamp**: assigned at the end of processing

---

**PRODUCER**:
The Producer is identified by a producer ID (integer or GUID).
It has the task of allocating the Workloads. Load A has a 0,5 probability of being produced. Load B has 0,375 probability of being produced. Load C has 0,125 probability of being produced. 1 load per second is produced.
The Producer assigns to the load:

- its ID
- an incremental integer for each load produced
- Production Timestamp

---

**WORKER**:
It executes the Workload (calls the Execute method) in parallel mode on each load that is presented to it. In the critical section there can be a **maximum of 4 Workloads** at the same time. At the end of the processing, it prints the identifiers of the Workload and the sum of the random bytes generated by the Execute.
It assigns the Processing Timestamp.

---

**CONSUMER**:
It consumes received workloads by printing:

- Workload identifiers
- It processes the random bytes contained in the workload, making the sum and printing the sum
- Production Timestamp
- Processing Timestamp
- Difference in milliseconds of timestamps

---

Any help/suggestions on how to accomplish it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using [SignalR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SignalR)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. Unfortunately I don't have to use any library. Only produce code by myself

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this? What difficulty did you encounter? What is your actual question?

Comment: I've read different guides about Producer/Consumer pattern and some about TCP client/server, but none of them satisfy me.
The "difficulty" is that I have never dealt with these topics, so my question is if someone can help or suggests me how/where I can start and/or proceed in this assignment. Thanks